# Verify SSL certificate from the custom path using python

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have installed apache web server. Generated SSL for the apache website. Got cert file and key. I wrote a python snippet to validate the ssl file  for the website. The certificate file path is stored in cer_auth. My code will access file in the cer_auth,validates it and provide the result. But it is showing error. How to solve it?

Here's the code:

```
import requests
host = '192.168.1.27'
host1 = 'https://'+host
#cer_auth = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
cer_auth = '/home/paulsteven/Apache_SSL/apache-selfsigned.crt'
print(host1)
try:
    requests.get(host1, verify= cer_auth)
    print("SSL Certificate Verified")
except:
    print("No SSL certificate")
```

Error i got:

```
https://192.168.1.27
/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:362: SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for 192.168.1.27 has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  SubjectAltNameWarning
No SSL certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

The old way of pointing certificates to hostnames was through the CommonName or `CN` field. This practice is rapidly changing due to changes in how browsers handle certificates. The current expectation is to have all hostnames and IPs in x509v3 extended fields in the certificate, named subjectAlternativeNames. The instructions you have followed were probably outdated.

Here's a mediocre guide into doing just that with OpenSSL

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX135602

If you want to sign for some IP addresses, the field name is `IP.1` instead of `DNS.1` like in the link above.